# bash script to remove directories based on modified file date

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm looking to create a bash script that recursively goes through directories and, starting at the very end of the tree, examines the files by date.  If the newest file is older than 90 days, go up one directory and check the same thing.  If there are no files newer than 90 days, remove the root directory.

*example* :

> /ftpdir/Site1/folder1/folder2

if folder 2 has no newer files, but folder 1 does, remove folder one, but keep Site1

I've written this in `AutoIT`, but now need it as a bash script and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks

EDIT:  I thought I was being clear, but let me clarify a few things:

1. I'm not looking to do this through the FTP protocol - this would run as a daily cron job
2. My FTP site is used as a dumping ground.  People create folders and subfolders, which in turn fills up space.  Most of the stuff is abandoned.
3. @Jonathan Leffler understands what I'm trying to do here.  Again, I apologize for the confusion.
4. I can post my original AutoIT script that shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

EDIT 2 - the original AutoIT script

```
#include <array.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <GuiConstants.au3>
#include <GuiButton.au3>
#Include <GuiListBox.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <ListBoxConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#Include <GuiListBox.au3>
#Include <GuiMonthCal.au3>


Global $FolderName = "\\ph-svr-web1\ftpsites"
Global $rootFolder
Global $now = _Date_Time_SystemTimeToDateStr(_Date_Time_GetSystemTime(), 1) 
Global $badSubs = 0, $olderThan = 90
Global $dirsToDeleteListBox, $topIndex, $TotalFoldersFound = 0
Global $ScanFoldersButton, $RemoveFoldersButton, $TotalFoldersFoundLabel, $TotalFoldersFoundNumber
Global $Calendar, $OlderThanNumberDays

Main()

Func Main()
    $MainWindow = GuiCreate("Remove Older Files From FTP Site", 900)
    GUISetFont(12)

    $dirsToDeleteListBox = GUICtrlCreateList("", 40, 35, 550, 300, BitOr($WS_BORDER, $WS_VSCROLL, $LBS_NOTIFY, $LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL, $WS_HSCROLL, $LBS_EXTENDEDSEL))

    $ScanFoldersButton = GuiCtrlCreateButton("Scan FTP Site", 40, 330)
    $RemoveFoldersButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Delete Selected Folders", 180, 330)
    _GUiCtrlButton_Enable($RemoveFoldersButton, False)

    $TotalFoldersFoundLabel = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Total Folders Found = ", 400, 335)
    $TotalFoldersFoundNumber = GUICtrlCreateLabel($TotalFoldersFound, 560, 335, 100)

    $Calendar = GUICtrlCreateMonthCal($MainWindow, 620, 35, 250, 220);, $MCS_NOTODAY)
    $OlderThanDateLabel = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Searching for files dated prior to:", 630, 270)
    GUISetFont(12, 600)
    $OlderThanDateValue = GUICtrlCreateLabel(SetCalendarDate($olderThan), 650, 300)
    $OlderThanNumberDays = GUICtrlCreateLabel("(" & $olderThan & " days)", 750, 300, 100)
    GUISetFont(12, 400)

    GUISetState()
    GUICtrlSetResizing ($MainWindow, 513 )

    While 1
        $GUIAction = GuiGetMsg()
        Switch $GUIAction
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                ExitLoop ; closes the GUI
            Case $ScanFoldersButton
                _GUICtrlButton_Enable($ScanFoldersButton, False)
                _GUiCtrlButton_Enable($RemoveFoldersButton, False)
                _GUICtrlListBox_ResetContent($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                $TotalFoldersFound = 0
                ScanFolder($FolderName)
                _GUICtrlButton_Enable($ScanFoldersButton, True)
                if $TotalFoldersFound > 0 then
                    _GUiCtrlButton_Enable($RemoveFoldersButton, True)
                    _GUICtrlListBox_SetTopIndex($dirsToDeleteListBox, 0)
                endif
            Case $RemoveFoldersButton
                _GUICtrlButton_Enable($ScanFoldersButton, False)
                _GUiCtrlButton_Enable($RemoveFoldersButton, False)
                RemoveFolders()
                _GUICtrlButton_Enable($ScanFoldersButton, True)
                _GUiCtrlButton_Enable($RemoveFoldersButton, True)
            Case $Calendar
                GUICtrlSetData($OlderThanDateValue, SetCalendarDate(_DateDiff('D', GUICtrlRead($Calendar), $now)))
        endswitch
    wend
EndFunc

Func SetCalendarDate($Days)
    $newDate = _DateAdd('D', -($Days), $now)
    GUICtrlSetData($Calendar, $newDate)
    $olderThan = $Days
    GUICtrlSetData($OlderThanNumberDays, "(" & $olderThan & " days)")
    Return $newDate
EndFunc

Func RemoveFolders()
    $Dirs = _GUICtrlListBox_GetSelItemsText($dirsToDeleteListBox)
    Switch $Dirs[0]
        Case 0
            MsgBox(276,"No folders selected","Please select folders to delete")
        Case Else
            ProgressOn("Deleting FTP Folders...", "Removing")
            $totalDirs = UBound($Dirs) - 1
            for $iI = 1 to $totalDirs
                DirRemove($Dirs[$iI], 1)
                ProgressSet((100 / $totalDirs), $Dirs[$iI])
                $removeFromList = _GUICtrlListBox_FindString($dirsToDeleteListBox, $Dirs[$iI])
                if $removeFromList > 0 then 
                    _GUICtrlListBox_BeginUpdate($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                    _GUICtrlListBox_DeleteString($dirsToDeleteListBox, $removeFromList)
                    _GUICtrlListBox_EndUpdate($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                    $TotalFoldersFound -= 1
                    GUICtrlSetData($TotalFoldersFoundNumber, $TotalFoldersFound)
                endif
            next
            ProgressOff()
            MsgBox(64, "Folders Deleted", "The selected folders have been deleted")
    EndSwitch
EndFunc

Func ScanFolder($SourceFolder)
    Local $Search
    Local $File
    Local $FileAttributes
    Local $FullFilePath
    Local $FileDate

    $Search = FileFindFirstFile($SourceFolder & "\*.*")

    While 1
        If $Search = -1 Then
            ExitLoop
        EndIf

        $File = FileFindNextFile($Search)
        If @error Then ExitLoop

        $FullFilePath = $SourceFolder & ("\" & $File)
        $FileAttributes = FileGetAttrib($FullFilePath)
        $FileDate = _ArrayToString(FileGetTime($FullFilePath), "/", 0, 2)
        $validRoot = ExtractRoot($FullFilePath)


        If StringInStr($FileAttributes,"D") Then
            if $validRoot >= 6 then
            select
                case _DateDiff('D', $FileDate, $now) <= $olderThan
                    $badSubs += 1
                    continuecase
                case StringCompare($rootFolder, $FullFilePath) = 0
                    if $badSubs = 0 then
                        _GUICtrlListBox_BeginUpdate($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                        $topIndex = _GUICtrlListBox_AddString($dirsToDeleteListBox, $rootFolder)
                        _GUICtrlListBox_SetTopIndex($dirsToDeleteListBox, $topIndex)
                        _GUICtrlListBox_EndUpdate($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                        $TotalFoldersFound += 1
                    else
                        $removeFromList = _GUICtrlListBox_FindString($dirsToDeleteListBox, $rootFolder)
                        if $removeFromList >= 0 then 
                            _GUICtrlListBox_BeginUpdate($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                            _GUICtrlListBox_DeleteString($dirsToDeleteListBox, $removeFromList)
                            _GUICtrlListBox_SetTopIndex($dirsToDeleteListBox, $topIndex)
                            _GUICtrlListBox_EndUpdate($dirsToDeleteListBox)
                            $TotalFoldersFound -= 1
                        endif
                        $badSubs = 0
                    endif
            endselect
            GUICtrlSetData($TotalFoldersFoundNumber, $TotalFoldersFound)
            endif
            ScanFolder($FullFilePath)
        EndIf
    Wend

    FileClose($Search)
EndFunc

Func ExtractRoot($FileName)
    $dirArray = StringSplit($FileName, "\")
    if $dirArray[0] >= 6 then
        $rootFolder = _ArrayToString($dirArray, "\", 1, 6)
    endif
    return $dirArray[0]
EndFunc
```

Edit 3:

Thanks to Rob, I've modified his script to my needs as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ];
then
    echo "You must enter a path after the script name"
    exit
fi

# Usage: "ThisProgram /path/to/root/of/files"

dirs=( $(find "${1}" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | sed 's:^./::'))
echo "$1"

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do

if [ $dir != $1 ]; then
    echo "$dir"
# First, get a list of all subdirs, in depth-first order
find "${dir:-.}" -depth -type d -print0 |
while read -r -d '' i
do

  # For each subdir, test to see if it matches two conditions. If either
  # condition fails, this subdir is not a candidate for deletion.
#  echo "Trying $i"

  #  First: is it at the lowest level, i.e. does it have any surviving children?
  [ "$(find "$i" -type d -print | wc -l)" -gt 1 ] && continue
#  echo "$i has no subdirs"

  # Second: does it have any recent files?
  [ "$(find "$i" -type f -mtime -90 | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] && continue
#  echo "$i has no new files"

  # If we got here, then this candidate has no subdirs and no recent files. Nuke it.
#  echo rm -rf "$i"
  echo "$i"
#  rm -rf "$i"
done

fi
```

Comment: What? this doesn't make much sense. You remove a directory if its newest file is older than 90 days and its parent directory also has no files newer than 90 days :S Why ? Make clear what you want to do. What happens if folder1 has two subdirs ? What's the condition to remove a directory ?

Comment: Think of it as a directory containing saved emails about some 'incident', with one file per email message.  If the most recent message is over 90 days old the incident is over and done with, and the whole directory can be deleted.  If any of the messages is less than 90 days old, keep all the files in the directory; the incident is still 'active' enough that we need all the information.  The example uses FTP.  It is still confusingly described.

Comment: edits made in the original question

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your requirements. What do you mean by "check the same thing" and by "remove the root directory"?

Comment: @Rob - check to see if there are files newer than 90 days.  As for remove the root directory, not (in this case) ftpdir, but a subfolder of said ftpdir.

Comment: If you still need assistance, please post your AutoIT script so we can see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

# Usage: "ThisProgram /path/to/root/of/files"
# If "/path/to/root/of/files" is not specified, use the current directory instead.

# First, get a list of all subdirs, in depth-first order
find "${1:-.}" -depth -type d -print0 |
while read -r -d '' i 
do

  # For each subdir, test to see if it matches two conditions. If either
  # condition fails, this subdir is not a candidate for deletion.
  echo "Trying $i"

  #  First: is it at the lowest level, i.e. does it have any surviving children?
  [ "$(find "$i" -type d -print | wc -l)" -gt 1 ] && continue
  echo "$i has no subdirs"

  # Second: does it have any recent files?
  [ "$(find "$i" -type f -mtime -90 | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] && continue
  echo "$i has no new files"

  # If we got here, then this candidate has no subdirs and no recent files. Nuke it.
  echo rm -rf "$i"

done
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get back to the office on Tuesday.

Comment: This seems to work, but how would i get around the whitespace issue?

Comment: I have updated the script to be whitespace-friendly. Note that the script now requires bash.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob.  I've posted an update to your script that's working perfectly for me.

Comment: The use of `find` repeatedly looks to me like severe overkill, and the pipeline to `wc` gives me shudders.  All you really need is probably `case $i/*/. in "$i/*/.") no subdirectories;;` to check for the presence of immediate child directories (subject to the setting of `nullglob`), and the second `find` should probably have a `-depth 0` at the very least.  The antipattern `[ $(whatever | wc -l) -gt 0 ]` is usually much more elegantly written `whatever | grep -q .` or even just plain old `whatever >/dev/null`.  See also the discussion on the UUOC page http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#wc

Comment: @tripleee - I agree about the `whatever | grep -q .` -- I kept that form for the `-gt 0` case to ease understanding, to be parallel to the `-gt 1` case that precedes it. Also agree about using glob instead of find. If I get to it, I'll post a version that responds to your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your question sounds pretty complicated for just deleting old files.

If you want to just delete files that are more than 90 days old:

```
find $DIR -type f -mtime +90d | xargs rm -f
```

If you want to delete an entire directory if all the files in that directory are 90 days old:

```
if test $(find $DIR -type f -mtime -90d | wc -l) -eq 0; then
  rm -rf $DIR
fi
```

If you want something different, please clarify your question :-)

Comment: The problem with this is that it removes files older than 90 days old even if there are younger files in the directory, which is not quite what the question asks for (if I understand it correctly; I might be confused because it is not all that clearly written).

Answer (score 0):

find answer here may you want :[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358113/command-that-deletes-all-old-files-folders-and-sub-folders)
`find /ftpdir/Site1/ -type f -mtime +90 -delete`
`find /ftpdir/Site1/ -type d -empty -mtime +90 -delete`